# Getting completely different weight values when using sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier with different random_state value for Logistic Regression

Tags: python

I believe, the weight should change slightly with different random state.
What could be the reason for getting different weights at every run with random_state = None

Following are the weights value for few runs( contains 3 features)
1)4.67100318,1.26129186,17.26554955
2)3.39793468,2.10265234,18.42484435
3)-2.08082186,1.25948975,10.37120852
4)3.71122156,0.93510126,16.63007864

Because of this fluctuations, I am not sure which random_state should I use and this is creating trouble while performing feature selection.
Please note that I am using data after performing standardisation.

I am using very simple code as below to train my model, as my data contain only 200 rows of data with 3 features

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
SGDClf = SGDClassifier(loss='log',random_state=1)
SGDClf.fit(X,Y)
```

Comment: Have you done some cross validation ? this could help reduce the fluctuation. And show the code you use so we can help more.

Comment: Hi Malo, I am not sure how do I apply CV in SGDClassifier. As per my understanding we perform CV for hyper parameter tuning. What is hyper parameter here? I am new to machine learning field, please bear with my silly questions if you feel so.

Answer (score 1):

[Machine learning models will produce different results on same dataset](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-does-the-model-produce-different-results-on-same-dataset-54486f951dbf), `random_state = None`,
the models generate a sequence of random numbers called [random seed](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-random-seeds-effectively-54a4cd855a79) used within the process of generating test, validation and training datasets from a given dataset, ex:`random_state = 1`.
Configurating a model's seed to a set value will ensure that the (weight) results  are reproducible.

[SGDClassifier()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) shuffles the entered data:

> The passed (random state) value will have an effect on the reproducibility of the
> results returned by the function (fit, split, or any other function
> like k_means). - [random state doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random_state)

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Hi Alex,  how will i make sure which weights are correct.... Since there is no correlation in the weight results everytime I run with different random state

Comment: They are all correct 'findings', the more you train your model (with different X and y (training data sets)), the better the model will become at predicting the weights. In other words, the more accurate your weight results will become.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your valuable answer